# C++11 cin input validation

Tags: c++, validation, c++11, lambda

What is the best way in C++11 (ie. using C++11 techniques) to validate cin input? I've read lots of other answers (all involving cin.ignore, cin.clear, etc.), but those methods seem clumsy and result in lots of duplicated code.

Edit: By 'validation', I mean that both well-formed input was provided, and that it satisfies some context-specific predicate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "validate". A read operation can succeed or fail, you can easily check for that since C++98. Hopefully you are not trying to create a user interface with std::cin, are you?

Comment: Certainly you're not suggesting that it's always a bad idea to ask for command-line input during the runtime of a cli program? Think of package managers that ask you to confirm changes (Y/N). What should you do if someone enters "Q#$IQGP@$"? Ask again, probably.

Comment: I don't use cin/cout for interaction (unless it's just "please enter a line"), it's too much work; ncurses and readline are much better tools for that.

Comment: Sure, but that's also not the problem I'm trying to solve. One shouldn't need to import the full power of readline or ncurses to ask a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting my attempt at a solution as an answer in the hopes that it is useful to somebody else. It is not necessary to specify a predicate, in which case the function will check only for well-formed input. I am, of course, open to suggestions.

```c
//Could use boost's lexical_cast, but that throws an exception on error,
//rather than taking a reference and returning false.
template<class T>
bool lexical_cast(T& result, const std::string &str) {
    std::stringstream s(str);
    return (s >> result && s.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0);
}

template<class T, class U>
T promptValidated(const std::string &message, std::function<bool(U)> condition = [](...) { return true; })
{
    T input;
    std::string buf;
    while (!(std::cout << message, std::getline(std::cin, buf) && lexical_cast<T>(input, buf) && condition(input))) {
        if(std::cin.eof())
            throw std::runtime_error("End of file reached!");
    }
    return input;
}
```

Here's an example of its usage:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double num = promptValidated<double, double>("Enter any number: ");
    cout << "The number is " << num << endl << endl;

    int odd = promptValidated<int, int>("Enter an odd number: ", [](int i) { return i % 2 == 1; });
    cout << "The odd number is " << odd << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If there's a better approach, I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Assuming this is in a header, I suggest removing the using statements or using directive from it. Also, you can move the `cin >> input` right into the condition, taking the place of `cin.fail()`. The output can also go in there to save another duped line. You'd also be better off taking your parameter by const ref.

Comment: Throwing an exception if `cin` hits `EOF` would be preferable to inifinite looping. And since you're already templating on `T`, you could template on `condition` as well, which would allow `condition` to take `T&` and transform `input` if needed or `const T&` to avoid copies if T is large.

Comment: I like those ideas, too! I made a few changes above to implement them. Is there a better way of varying just the modifiers on T, as opposed to requiring a second parameter?

Comment: What about a plain getline() followed by a boost::lexical_cast? No more bit flags handling on cin.

Comment: I definitely agree with the getline() approach, since as it stands "34cats" will evaluate to 34 and cause the next input to fail once, but I was hoping for a standard-library solution. I could perhaps use a stringstream and check that the whole input was used?

Comment: Yes, istringstream is the verbose way to implement lexical_cast.

Answer (score 0):

If by validation you mean that when you want an `int` you want to know if an `int` was really entered, then just put the input in an `if` condition:

```
int num;

while (!(std::cin >> num))
{
    std::cout << "Whatever you entered, it wasn't an integer\n";
}

std::cout << "You entered the integer " << num << '\n';
```

Comment: I think the main point is persisting until valid input is entered.

Comment: You forgot to clear the bits; if the read operation failed, the bits indicating the failure are still set and will continue to fail.

Comment: @DanielKO I didn't make a complete drop-in code, it's just an example to show how the broad strokes.