# Can we limit user input in C++?

Tags: c++

The problem is when the user input is = 9999999999 then the console is returning all the values.
I want to limit this input by using simple **else if** statement if someone tried to put the value for a, b = 9999999999 then user must get the warning as I defined in my code.
I can control it by using double instead of int but this is not a solution.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    cout << "Enter Value for A: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter Value for B: ";
    cin >> b;

    if (a > b)
        {
        cout << "A is Greater than B " << endl; //This will be printed only if the statement is True
        }
    else if ( a < b )
        {
        cout << "A is Less than B " << endl; //This will be printed if the statement is False
        }
        else if ( a, b > 999999999 )
        {
        cout << " The Value is filtered by autobot !not allowed " << endl; //This will be printed if the statement is going against the rules
        }
     else
        {
        cout << "Values are not given or Unknown " << endl; //This will be printed if the both statements are unknown
        }

    cout << "Enter Value for C: ";
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Enter Value for D: ";
    cin >> d;

    if (c < d)
    {
        cout << c << " < " << d << endl; //This will be printed if the statement is True
        }
        else if ( c > d )
        {
        cout << "C is Greater than D " << endl; //This will be printed if the statement is False
        }
        else
        {
        cout << c << " unknown " << d << endl; //This will be printed if the statement is Unknown
        }
}
```

Comment: `if ( a, b > 999999999 )` doesn't do what you want. it's same as  `if ( b > 999999999 )`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I must declare them partially in 2 lines of codes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate user input a number and the number greater than 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594273/how-to-validate-user-input-a-number-and-the-number-greater-than-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 cin input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864877/c11-cin-input-validation)

Comment: @ChrisMM Not exactly because I want to solve it by using int, not float or double.

Comment: @Саша you have to use logic operators or std::max, or something. Comma is a sequence operator and it returns last value in sequence

Comment: Why not using `long long int` ?

Comment: @Саша, it's the same thing. That example just uses doubles.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I just want to return an objection by using else if statement if the user tried to put the value larger than 999999999

Comment: @Damien yes it is possible but I want to return an objection or warning by using the else if statement

Comment: Read up on the C++ [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yes it works well by using logical operator with else if statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example function which ensures valid input. I've made it take in a min and max value too, but you don't necessarily need them, since 999999999 is going to be out of the range of `int` anyway, which causes `cin` to fail. It will wait for valid input though.

```
int getNum( int min, int max ) {
    int val;
    while ( !( cin >> val ) || val < min || val > max ) {
        if ( !cin ) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore( 1000, '\n' );
        }
        cout << "You entered an invalid number\n";
    }
    return val;
}

int main() {
    int a = getNum( 0, 12321 );
}
```

EDIT: Well, now you just modified your question to have *using simple else if statement*, changing the answers. The answer then, is simply no. Since `cin` would fail, you can't realistically do a check. Also, it would never be true since `999999999` is greater than `INT_MAX` on any implementation I can think of.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I want to do it with just   else if  statement.

Comment: @Саша, not in your initial question. Again though, the answer is no.

Comment: @Саша, the issue is with `999999999` being too large for `int` (on any implementation I can think of). This causes `cin` to fail. If you wanted to limit to `99999999`, then you could use `if` and `else`. The advantage to my proposed solution, is that it also handles when a user puts in something like "adas" for an integer, which obviously isn't valid.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (std::min(a, b) > 999999999)
```

is one fix, although `if (a > 999999999)` would work in your case due to the way you've arrange your `if` block. Take care though to check that `999999999` is within the range of an `int` - the C++ standard does not require it to be. The expression

```
if (a, b > 999999999)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (b > 999999999)
```

with, formally, `a` being *evaluated* but the result discarded.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value of int is 2147483647 which is less than 9999999999. If you want to input 9999999999, you have to use a different data type.

Edit:
I guess I have to give a more in depth explanation on why you have to use a different data type.

C++ is different from Java. In Java if you try to input 9999999999 to an int, it would throw an exception saying the number is too larger, and the program quits.

However, in C++, when you cin a number that is too large, cin would go into failure mode. In failure mode, cin would take the closest in-range value and silently ignores any further cin and leaving them as the initial value. Most of the time the initial value is 0; however, depending on your heap space, the variable may be assigned a garbage value. Hence your a would have an value of 2147484647 and b is left as its initialized value 0 or a random value. 
Thus your first if statement would evaluate to true and cout "A is Greater than B".

In short, the maximum value of int is 2147483647, so if you want to input 9999999999, you have to use a different data type.

Comment: No that's wrong. If `int` had that range (it probably does) then the *type* of 9999999999 would be wider than `int` (a `long` or possibly a `long long`), and `b` converted implicitly to that type. Your analysis is correct in Java, which is one reason why that language will not go the distance!

Comment: @Bathsheba, int does have this range. If you actually runs this code and input 9999999999, a would be given the value of int max, and b would be given a garbage value automatically, which is why all the values are returned.

Comment: @Bathsheba `std::cin` would fail on trying to read this value as it is out of range of `int`

Comment: @Bathsheba the code won't even reach the second if statement, since a is already greater than b with the input of 9999999999.

Comment: `int` in C++ annoys me sometimes.  All the Standard says about its size is `int` is at least 16 bits and no larger than `long`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Exactly. I guess i am not clear enough on my answer.

Comment: Side note: The described behaviour is different if compiling to a Standard revision older than C++11 (and this is still the default with some commonly used compiler distributions (that you probably shouldn't be using anymore)). In older Standards the variable is left unmodified on read failure. That means if you read into an uninitialized value, it's still uninitialized. If the last value read into the variable was pi, it's still pi.

Comment: Another note: When you want to be absolutely sure your data type can hold the data you need use a [fixed width integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). In this case you want `int_fast64_t` or `int_least64_t`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the input value and if it exceeds the predefined limit request for another input

```
int limit = 99999;
int a, b;
cout << "Input a : ";
cin >> a;
while(a>limit){
    cout << "Input exceeds limit reinput a : ";
    cin >> a;
}
cout << "Input b : ";
cin >> b;
while(b>limit){
    cout << "Input exceeds limit reinput b : ";
    cin >> b;
}
```

Comment: Your condition in your loops is backwards